# How to configure IIS with IPv6

Tags: iis, ipv6, windows-server-2016

Recently one of my apps got rejected by the App Store because it didn't work on an IPv6 network. I think my problem is located at API level on my windows server.

Apple tells you to run tests on the domain with [this test](http://ipv6-test.com/validate.php). Using this test I found out that no AAAA record was set on the domain. That was easily fixed. Then I ran the test again and got the following results.

```
Tested on       Tue, 10 Oct 2017 12:57:26 GMT
AAAA DNS record     <my-IPv6-address>
IPv6 web server     web server is unreachable : No route to host
IPv6 DNS server
```

Looking at the error message `web server is unreachable: No route to host` it seems that something on my windows server is not configured properly. I have no clue on what I supposed to be configuring though. So how can I configure IIS (and/or application) so this test will succeed?

I have the API running on a Windows machine with Windows Server 2016 and IIS 10.

Comment: What is the IPv6 address of your machine? Is it statically configured, did your hosting provider give it to you, or did you put a link-local address (starting with `fe80:`) in DNS and expected that to work? More background information is needed to answer this.